# JTextArea not updating when it should

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, model-view-controller

Hello StackOverflowers,

I'm currently working on my first Client/Server application and facing a problem that doesn't make sense to me at all. Please note that I'm new to network programming and working with runnables/threads.

I'm using the MVC pattern for my application, so I have a `ServerController`, `ServerView` and `ServerModel`.

Now there's a method in my `ServerController` which basically has 2 tasks.

1. Update the Server GUI - It is supposed to write a String "Server is starting..." in a `JTextArea` so the user knows the application did not crash
2. Invoke the Server

   ```
   public ActionListener startServerListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
           //Update GUI 
           view.updateServerNotice(new String("Server is starting..."));

           //Start Server in new thread
           Thread t1 = new Thread(model);
           t1.start();
           Thread.sleep(1000);

           view.showNotification(model.hostAvailabilityCheck() + "");
          } catch (Exception ex)
            {
              view.showNotification("Server is started already!");
            }
     }
   };
   ```

My problem is, that the `view.updateServerNotice(new String("Server is starting..."));` method gets executed but doesn't show up in the GUI before the Server isn't started. So currently it is like the button is clicked, then there's a little delay (due to the `sleep()`) and THEN, after the server started, the GUI gets updated with "Server is starting...".

This doesn't make sense to me since the GUI updated is definitely executed before the new thread is created.

I hope someone sees something that I don't and can help me. It's not really a big problem, but I'm really curious why this is happening.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) But as a WAG, don't block the EDT.

Comment: why do you need `Thread.sleep(1000);` ? I think that line blocks your GUI...

Comment: As the others already pointed out, you're blocking the event dispatch thread (EDT) with that `Thread.sleep(1000);`. This thread is responsible for updating the UI so when you send it to sleep it won't do that. Put the sleep and the call to `showNotification(...)` into another thread (or the runnable you're passing to `t1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing (and AWT, and in fact many UI frameworks in most environments, not just Java) is single-threaded: nothing is going to be drawn as long as your ActionListener is running.

What you can do is running your code in a background thread, however in this case another issue kicks in: single-threaded UI frameworks do not really like random interactions from other threads. While direct access may work sometimes, the 'legal' approach is to send actions packed into some Runnable form, using SwingUtilities.invokeLater or invokeAndWait (I am using this latter one here, so your message will be visible for sure):

```
public ActionListener startServerListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      new Thread(new Runnable({
        public void run(){
          try{
            // Update GUI #1
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                view.updateServerNotice(new String("Server is starting..."));
              }
            });

            //Start Server in new thread
            Thread t1 = new Thread(model);
            t1.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Update GUI #2
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                view.showNotification(model.hostAvailabilityCheck() + "");
              }
            });
          }catch(Exception ex){/*...*/}
        }
      })).start();
    }catch(Exception ex){/*...*/}
  }
};
```

Beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: Hey tevemadar, thank you for helping me. I think I will try to handle my issue in another way since I find this solution pretty illegible. Anyway, thank you for showing me an alternative approach to solve my problem :)